# I need an information about Chat Messages, Send Sms, Make a call, voice command and face recognition?

Tags: sms, call, flutter, voice-recognition, face-recognition

I need an information like shown below to make a prototype Flutter app.
Does Flutter capable for these? Can I find any documentation and where?
Can I find any examples similar to these?

**1) Help Desk Chat Messages:** (Like a Help Desk)
   Many user ask the questions and 2 or 3 (max 10) will give the answers.

**2) Send Sms to Help Desk:**
   Mostly after working hours users send questions to Help desk.

**3) Make Call to Help Desk:**
   Users for immediate questions calls the Help Desk.

**4) Voice Command for menus:**
   User activates app menu (like activating the menu or asking “what is 
   my balance” etc.) via using their voice. Like a Siri but much cut 
   down version.

**5) Iris Login:**
   User can login the app once and if they needed they can use Face
   recognition to use their face scan so next time they don’t need 
   to use 4 steps login. Next time they use face recognition to login to 
   app.

Comment: Of course. Flutter is capable of anything you can do in Android or iOS. You might have to work with native code, but that is the only restriction.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot thank you.  I don't mine with native code. So where I can get these information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter is capable of doing anything you can do with native. Because Flutter is still very young, there might not be Dart solutions available (yet), but it's all possible if you write native code.

I like to keep track of this GitHub rep: https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter. It contains links to some libraries that may help you with your prototype.

Comment: Thanks Christopher Araujo